# Protocol on Objective-C iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, protocols

I have some problem with my app and a protocol. I can't post image (...) but my Storyboard contains two controller. First is Main Menu controller with a UIButton. When the button is pressed by the user, a Table view appear with its controller "Available Server controller".

Well, The Main-Menu controller expose the following protocol:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Client.h"
#import "MyRstAaAppDelegate.h"

@class MyRstAaClientViewController;

@protocol ClientNetworkDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)serverBecameAvaiable:(NSString *)peerID;
-(void)serverBecameUnavailable:(NSString *)peerID;
-(void)didConnectToServer:(NSString *)peerID;
-(void)didDisconnectFromServer:(NSString *)peerID;
@end

@interface MyRstAaClientViewController : UIViewController <ClientDelegate>

#pragma PROPERTIES
//Delegate property
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ClientNetworkDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

And the Available Server Table view controller implements the protocol's methods to reload table data and to do other stuff. This is its code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyRstAaClientViewController.h"

@interface MyRstAaClientServerListTableViewController : UITableViewController <ClientNetworkDelegate>

@end
```

...
...

And the .m

```
#import "MyRstAaClientServerListTableViewController.h"

@interface MyRstAaClientServerListTableViewController ()

//Client shared istance
@property (nonatomic, strong) Client *client;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyRstAaClientViewController *mainController;
@end

@implementation MyRstAaClientServerListTableViewController

#pragma PROPERTIES
@synthesize client = _client;
@synthesize mainController = _mainController;

#pragma INITIALIZATION FUNCTIONS
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyRstAaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyRstAaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.client = appDelegate.client;

    if(_mainController == nil)
        _mainController = [[MyRstAaClientViewController alloc]init];
    [self.mainController setDelegate:self];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma DELEGATES
-(void)serverBecameAvaiable:(NSString *)peerID;
{
    //Reload table data
    [self.tableView reloadData];

#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"CLIENT-SERVERLIST:: Server become Available");
#endif
}
-(void)serverBecameUnavailable:(NSString *)peerID;
{
    //Reload table data
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"CLIENT-SERVERLIST:: Server become unavaiable");
    #endif
}
- (void)didConnectToServer:(NSString *)peerID
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"CLIENT-SERVERLIST:: Server become Available");
    #endif
}
- (void)didDisconnectFromServer:(NSString *)peerID
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"CLIENT-SERVERLIST:: did Disconnect From Server");
    #endif
}
```

This is an example of delegate call on the .m file of MainMenu controller of my app

```
#import "MyRstAaClientViewController.h"

@interface MyRstAaClientViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) Client *client;

@end

@implementation MyRstAaClientViewController

#pragma PROPERTIES
@synthesize client = _client;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

-(void)Client:(Client *)client serverBecameUnavailable:(NSString *)peerID
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"CLIENT-HOME:: Server become unavaiable");
#endif

    //Call delegate methodå
    [self.delegate serverBecameUnavailable:peerID];
}
```

The problem is that when I run my app on my iPhone, and I go under "Available Server" list view, I can see, for example,  on the output the string: **CLIENT-HOME:: Server become unavaiable** but the corresponding delegate function in the Table view controller is never called. Why??

There's something wrong in use of delegate and protocol pattern?

Comment: Forgot to assign the `delegate`?

Comment: No, Into the TableView controller in ViewDidLoad I put the assignment... I think...

Comment: The method is spelled 'viewDidLoad', not 'ViewDidLoad' (i.e. lower case v). Have you spelled it correctly?

Comment: Use NSLogs to check the values of delegates at various points in your code.